# Loop stopped on half of data

Tags: list, python-2.7, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I parse html file locating on my disk to get some data of it.I locate the data but I cant add it all to list.Only half of them successfully appended to list.html structure do not changed.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

Numeric = []
x1 = []
dara = urlopen("file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/SuperLoto_Results__539-796.htm").read()
soup =BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/SuperLoto_Results__539-796.htm").read(),'lxml')
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
          col = row.find_all('td')
          x1.extend(col[4])
          Numeric.extend(col[0])
```

html file I parsed

[image]

Comment: When you say only half of them append, do both arrays `x1` and `Numeric` have the problem?  If so, what line does it stop at?

Comment: Both have length of 127 at the end, but it should be 257

Comment: What does row 127 look like?  Do you have a link to the website this file came from?

Comment: I dont have link becaouse its downloaded html But 127 the same like anothers one

Comment: You can download from here http://www.ex.ua/231196981154.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran it successfully in Python 3.4.  Here is my code and the output.  Please note that I changed `x1.extend(col[4])` to `x1.extend(col[3])` because you indicated you wanted the data in the fourth cell

```
Numeric = []
x1 = []
soup =BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("file:///C:/Users/Home/Downloads/SuperLoto_Results__539-796.htm").read(),'lxml')
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    try:
        col = row.find_all('td')
        x1.extend(col[3])
        Numeric.extend(col[0])
    except:
        print("error")
print(x1.__len__())
print(Numeric.__len__())
```

The output is:

```
error
259
259
```

Comment: I can't tell, except for the `col[4]` your code seems to be OK.  You can run my code on Python 2.7, you just access the `soup` differently and don't use parentheses for `print`